# SQL query: To find an actors who did more films with Quentin Tarantino

Tags: sql, sqlite, jupyter

I'm suppose to find all the actors that made more movies with Quentin Tarantino than any other director

I wrote the following SQL query, to find the number films an actor did with a particular director

```
SELECT  Director,  Actor, count(*) As total_films FROM (
    SELECT a.name as Director, c.title as Movie
    FROM Person a
    Inner Join M_director b
    ON TRIM(b.PID) = a.PID
    Inner Join Movie c
    ON TRIM(b.MID) = c.MID
    GROUP BY a.name, c.title

) t1
Inner Join 
(
    Select x.name as Actor, z.title as Movie
    FROM Person x
    Inner Join M_cast y
    ON TRIM(y.PID) = x.PID
    Inner Join Movie z
    ON TRIM(y.MID) = z.MID
    GROUP BY x.name, z.title

) t2
ON  t1.movie = t2.movie
GROUP BY t1.director, t2.Actor
ORDER BY total_films DESC
```

I got the following output:

```
                 Director                  Actor  total_films
0             David Dhawan           Shashi Kiran           23
1             David Dhawan           Shashi Kiran           23
2             David Dhawan             Kader Khan           20
3             David Dhawan          Shakti Kapoor           20
4             David Dhawan             Kader Khan           20
5             David Dhawan          Shakti Kapoor           20
-
-
-
-
-
39000        Zunaid Memon       Satyendra Kapoor             1
139001        Zunaid Memon            Sergio Kato            1
139002        Zunaid Memon      Sulabha Deshpande            1
139003        Zunaid Memon        Vaibhav Jhalani            1
139004        Zunaid Memon            Vivek Madan            1
```

Would appreciate your insights on this issue.

Comment: The group by in the sub queries doesn't server any obvious purpose what did you hope to achieve by this?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue - where did you get the data?

Comment: P.Salmon: This an assignment question from an online course I'm taking. Yes, the group by in the sub queries does not serve any purpose I just wanted check if the duplication of actor and director pair could be due no group by in subqueries, turns out thats no the case.

Strawberry: I've attached the db file I got for this assignment, along with the schema diagram and the code shared above, I hope this meets the requirements of  minimal reproducible example

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wDGML7Wna91TB_mQec6InDVKyZPtHE6m/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The link appears to be a sqllite file - is your question about sqllite or mysql?

Comment: Sqlite, actally I'm using this file , loading it on Jupyter notebook and running the queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your correct query for the number of movies between an actor and director is:

```
SELECT pd.name as Director, pa.name as actor, COUNT(*)
FROM M_director d JOIN
     Person pd
     ON pd.pid = d.pid JOIN
     M_cast c
     ON c.MID = d.MID JOIN
     Person pa
     ON pa.PID = c.PID
GROUP BY pd.name, pa.name
```

Note the use of table aliases that are abbreviations for the table names.  This is important if you are learning SQL.

The "more films with" is tricky.  The simplest method is window functions, but this is tricky because you don't want ties either.  So:

```
SELECT da.*
FROM (SELECT pd.pid, pd.name as Director, pa.pid, pa.name as actor, COUNT(*) as cnt,
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY pa.pid ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY pa.pid, COUNT(*)) as num_with_cnt,
      FROM M_director d JOIN
           Person pd
           ON pd.pid = d.pid JOIN
           M_cast c
           ON c.MID = d.MID JOIN
           Person pa
           ON pa.PID = c.PID
      GROUP BY pd.pid, pd.name, pa.pid, pa.name
     ) da
WHERE director = 'Yash Chopra' AND
      seqnum = 1 AND
      num_with_cnt = 1;
```

If ties were allowed, then you can remove the `num_with_cnt` logic.

Comment: Hi Gordan,

Thank you for looking into this. 

I understood the rank () function, basically, we're partioning the results by each  actor , calculating the rank respective to the number of films he/she has done with a partcular director and at the end we're looking for actors who have worked with Yash chopra and who have a rank of 1, indicating they've done highest no.of films with him.

However , can you please explain how 

COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY pa.pid, COUNT(*)) as num_with_cnt, works ?

I understd it is related to avoidng the tie condition, however, I'm not sure how it works

Comment: @HemanthRavavarapu . . . The `COUNT()` is just saying that for the top count, there is only one row -- that is, eliminating ties.

Comment: I understood the crux of what the stament COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY pa.pid, COUNT(*)) does, i.e after the ranks have been assigned, make sure there are no ties, however, I'm not getting how the syntax behaves, and how it deals in case there is a tie i.e how does it determine which count to give preference in case of a tie.

Comment: @HemanthRavavarapu . . . It doesn't.  The information is used in the outer `where` clause.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to join M_Cast table and M_Director table, but since there is **lots of data in M_cast table**, because it gives all the cast (Person ids - actors/actress) for all the movies. So Joining any table with M_Cast is a **very time consuming task**.
So I have come up with a little **optimization** to this simple join.
Lets go back to our question - > We need to find actors/actress who have done more movies with director - "Yash Chopra".
**Steps:**
**1. We will first find Person who have done atleast one movie with "Yash Chopra"**

```
    SELECT Trim(pid)  
    FROM m_cast  
    WHERE Trim(mid) IN (SELECT Trim(mid)  
                        FROM m_director  
                        WHERE Trim(pid) = (SELECT Trim(pid)   
                                           FROM   person   
                                           WHERE  NAME LIKE '%Yash Chopra%'  
                                          )  
                       )
```

2. We can be sure that, the final output will contain Person from above query only, there won't be any other Person, which is not present in the above query.
   Its true, that the above query gives all the Person who have done Movies with "Yash Chopra", But we need only the Person, who have done more movies with "Yash Chopra" than any other director. So, we can say that we will get a **subset of the above query result, as our final output**. So, we will not join the entire M_Cast table. We can add a condition, we can take only the Person PID which we got from above query.

   ```
    SELECT *  
    FROM m_cast  
    WHERE Trim(pid) IN (SELECT Trim(pid)   
                        FROM m_cast  
                        WHERE Trim(mid) IN (SELECT Trim(mid)  
                                            FROM m_director  
                                            WHERE Trim(pid) = (SELECT Trim(pid)   
                                                               FROM   person   
                                                               WHERE  NAME LIKE '%Yash Chopra%'
                                                              )
                                           )
                       )
   ```
3. Now we will Join above M_Cast table with M_Director and get the count of Movies done by each Person with each Director

   ```
    SELECT Count(mc.mid) AS Movies, 
           md.pid        AS Director_PID, 
           mc.pid        AS Actor_PID 
    FROM m_director md 
         INNER JOIN (SELECT *
                     FROM m_cast
                     WHERE Trim(pid) IN (SELECT Trim(pid) 
                                         FROM m_cast
                                         WHERE Trim(mid) IN (SELECT Trim(mid)
                                                             FROM m_director
                                                             WHERE Trim(pid) = (SELECT Trim(pid)   
                                                                                FROM person   
                                                                                WHERE  NAME LIKE '%Yash Chopra%'
                                                                               )
                                                            )
                                        ) 
                    )as mc
                  ON Trim(md.mid) = Trim(mc.mid) 
    GROUP  BY actor_pid, director_pid
   ```
4. Now we have Person with count of movies with each director. We will find the max movie count for each Person, and if the max no. of movies is done by Yash Chopra, we will consider that Person.
5. We also have to make sure, we don't include Yash Chopra as an actor into this.
   So, Now our final query will be as below,

   ```
    SELECT p.NAME,   
           max_movies   
    FROM   person p 
           INNER JOIN (SELECT director_pid,   
                              Max(movies) AS max_movies,   
                              actor_pid   
                       FROM   (SELECT Count(mc.mid) AS Movies, 
                                      md.pid        AS Director_PID, 
                                      mc.pid        AS Actor_PID 
                               FROM m_director md 
                                    INNER JOIN (SELECT *
                                                FROM m_cast
                                                WHERE Trim(pid) IN (SELECT Trim(pid)     
                                                                    FROM m_cast
                                                                    WHERE Trim(mid) IN (SELECT Trim(mid)
                                                                                        FROM m_director    
                                                                                        WHERE Trim(pid) = (SELECT Trim(pid) 
                                                                                                           FROM   person     
                                                                                                           WHERE  NAME LIKE '%Yash Chopra%'
                                                                                                          ) 
                                                                                   )
                                                               ) 
                                           )as mc
                                        ON Trim(md.mid) = Trim(mc.mid) 
                           GROUP  BY actor_pid, director_pid
                           ) 
                    GROUP  BY actor_pid
                    ) 
                ON Trim(p.pid) = Trim(actor_pid) 
    WHERE  director_pid = (SELECT Trim(pid) 
                           FROM   person 
                           WHERE  NAME LIKE '%Yash Chopra%'
                          ) 
           AND Trim(p.pid) <> (SELECT Trim(pid) 
                               FROM   person 
                               WHERE  NAME LIKE '%Yash Chopra%'
                               ) 
    ORDER  BY max_movies DESC
   ```
6. Output will be as below (227 records)

   - Name             max_movies
   - Jagdish Raj         11
   - Manmohan Krishna    10
   - Iftekhar             9
   - Shashi Kapoor        7
   - Waheeda Rehman       5
   - ... ... ...

Answer (score 0):

```
Select tadc.actorID as actorID, tadc.actorName as actorName, (tadc.total_director_count*1.0) /2 as
    tc, 
    ifnull((select count(Distinct mc2.MID) from 
    Person P3 join M_Cast mc2 on P3.PID=mc2.PID 
    join M_Director md2 on md2.MID=mc2.MID 
    join Person P4 on P4.PID=md2.PID 
    where P4.Name like '%Yash Chopra%' 
    and P3.PID = tadc.actorID 
    group by P3.PID, P4.PID), 0 
    ) as yash_director_count 
    from ( 
    select adc.actorID, adc.actorName, count(DISTINCT adc.directorID) as total_director_count 
    from 
    (select P1.PID as actorID, P1.Name as actorName, P2.PID as directorID, P2.Name as directorName, count(Distinct mc1.MID) as movie_count 
    from 
    Person P1 join M_Cast mc1 on P1.PID=mc1.PID 
    join M_Director md1 on md1.MID=mc1.MID 
    join Person P2 on P2.PID=md1.PID 
    group by P1.PID, P2.PID 
    order by P1.Name, P2.Name) as adc 
    group by adc.actorID 
    order by total_director_count ASC 
    ) as tadc 
    where yash_director_count > tc
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score -1):

`"select Director, Actor, Count(*) as Movies_with_YashChopra from` 
                `(select p1.name as Director, m1.title as Movie from Person p1` `Inner Join M_Director md on TRIM(mb.pid)=p1.pid` 
                `Inner Join Movie m1 on TRIM(md.mid)=m1.mid and a.name LIKE` `'Yash%' Group By p1.name, m1.title) t1 Inner Join` 
          `(select p2.name as Actor,m2.title as Movie from Person p2 Inner Join` `M_Cast mc on TRIM(mc.pid)=p2.pid` 
    `Inner Join Movie m2 on TRIM(mc.mid)=m2.title Group By p2.name,m2.title)t2`
                `on t1.Movie=t2.Movie Group By t1.Director, t2.Actor Order By` `Movies_with_YashChopra DESC"`

I think it should be like this only movies with yashchopra