# SQL operational error while searching for a query in the database

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

This is a follow up from this question: 
[SQL query, IMDB data : To find an actors who did more films with Yash chopra than any other director](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57743908/sql-query-imdb-data-to-find-an-actors-who-did-more-films-with-yash-chopra-tha/57911852#57911852)

```
actors = pd.read_sql_query('''SELECT da.*
FROM (SELECT pd.pid, pd.name as Director, pa.pid, pa.name as actor, COUNT(*) as cnt,
         RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY pa.pid ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY pa.pid, COUNT(*)) as num_with_cnt,
FROM M_director d JOIN
       Person pd
       ON pd.pid = d.pid JOIN
       M_cast c
       ON c.MID = d.MID JOIN
       Person pa
       ON pa.PID = c.PID
  GROUP BY pd.pid, pd.name, pa.pid, pa.name
 ) da
WHERE director = 'Yash Chopra' AND
  seqnum = 1 AND
  num_with_cnt = 1;''',conn)
```

This isn't working as expected and throwing an error:

> OperationalError: near "FROM": syntax error During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: DatabaseError Traceback (most recent call last) in 14 WHERE director = 'Yash Chopra' AND 15 seqnum = 1 AND ---> 16 num_with_cnt = 1''',conn)

I'm pretty new to SQL - can anyone please tell me what went wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a comma before `FROM`.

Comment: removing the comma doesn't show an error,but it's not giving the desired output. It's showing an empty table instead.

Comment: Remove the semicolon at the end. It's not part of SQL.

Comment: What's the engine? MySQL or SQLite?

Comment: @The Impaler i am importing  sqlite3 in python

Comment: @The Impaler removing the semicolon doesn't make a difference. The syntax error was due to the comma before FROM as Gordon answered. However, It's still showing an  empty table.

Comment: @TheImpaler  For a single statement a semicolon is optional for either MySQL or sqlite.  Whether or not it's part of the SQL standard, both systems support it as a delimiter between statements and it doesn't hurt anything to just leave it as is.

Comment: @enviz  Now that the error is gone, its up to you to determine why the results are empty.  Without the full data set there is likely no way for anyone to identify the reason (outside some obvious logic error).  What you should do now is systematically perform "partial" queries to make sure each part works... joins, WHERE conditions, nested queries.  Honestly that should be how to construct a complex query in the first place.  You write one piece and test it, then incorporate it in a more complex query.

Comment: The window `PARTITION BY pa.pid ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC` looks very suspicious to me.  The ORDER BY clause specifies the order of rows within the partitioned sets.  Ordering by `COUNT(*)` within a partition should be ineffective since it will simply count all rows in the partition and will be the same for each row.  Sorting on the same value is pointless.  I think the other window function named `num_with_cnt` is also not correct.